# MPXJ in .NET Update MS Project file and convert to json

Tags: c#, ms-project, mpxj

I'm using the MPXJ library in .NET for parsing MS Project (MPP) files and convert it to JSON for my web application. The problem is that I can't update the links in the file to get the latest data at the moment (press F9 on MSProject). Any ideas?

I tried projectFile.updateStructure(); but unfortunately it doesn't work

```
ProjectReader reader = new UniversalProjectReader();
ProjectFile projectFile = reader.read("inputFile.mpp");

foreach (Task task in projectFile.Tasks){
   Console.Out.WriteLine(task.Name)
}
projectFile.updateStructure();
ProjectWriter writer = ProjectWriterUtility.getProjectWriter("outputFile.json");
writer.write(projectFile, "outputFile.json");
```

Comment: If you are looking to have the linked schedules flow through and update the dates for the down-stream tasks you'll need to open the file in the MS Project application so that the scheduling engine can do those calculations.

Comment: As Rachel notes in a separate comment here, you'll need to use MS Project to recalculate the schedule. I'm planning to add this functionality to MPXJ but that's a long term aim.